# doesn't call onMenuItemClick for first time - SherlockListActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, onclicklistener, optionmenu

I use SherlockListActivity, 
I created ActionBar with one item & its clickListener
when i click on it for first time after creating activity, doesn't call onMenuItemClick, but in every click after first click, work with no problem

Why ?

```
private void BuildTopActionBar() {
        BitmapDrawable bg = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.ic_action_bg);
        bg.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(bg);

        this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        this.getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("bookmarks");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This is called when the Home (Up) button is pressed in the Action Bar.
            finish();
            return true;
        case add_bookmark_item:
            // add
            item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    customAmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new customAmbilWarnaDialog(
                            BookMarksActivity.this, 0xffffffff,
                            new OnAmbilWarnaListener() {

                                public void onCancel(
                                        customAmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {
                                }

                                public void onOk(customAmbilWarnaDialog dialog,
                                        int color, String name, int hasName) {
                                    myDbHelper.AddNewBookmark(name,
                                            currentPageNum, color, hasName);
                                    // code
                                    lv.smoothScrollToPosition((lv.getCount() - 1));
                                }
                            });
                    dialog.show();                  
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.add(0, add_bookmark_item, 0, "add bookmark")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.bookmark_add)
                .setShowAsAction(
                        MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW
                                | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is that you're calling the `item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {...` in the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method.

This means it will be set the first time you click the `menuItem` (and then reset on every click) and the code inside it will only run once you've clicked it at least once.

either call this in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` or simply move the code from `onMenuItemClick()` to the switch/case