# action bar item click listener does not work at the first click

Tags: android, android-actionbar, onclicklistener, menuitem

I have favourite button on action bar and when user clicks on it,at the OnClickListener information is saved to database or deleted from database. **But on click listener works in second click not at the first one.So function doesn't save or delete anything at the first click but it does everything with the second click**
onOptionsItemSelected function works well because other items in the action bar works at the first click.
this part from the onOptionsItemSelected;

```
 case R.id.action_favourite:
            String buttonTitle = item.getTitle().toString();
            if(buttonTitle.equals("Remove from favourites")){
                //item.setChecked(true);
                checked = true;}
            else {//item.setChecked(false);
                checked = false;}
            item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new FavouriteStarListener(getActivity(), Integer.parseInt(cinemaid),name,url,ll,Integer.parseInt(movieNo),phone,checked));
            return true;
```

and here is the listener;

```
public class FavouriteStarListener implements android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {

Context context;
int cinemaId;
String name,url,ll,phone;
int movieNumber;
boolean checked;

public FavouriteStarListener(Context context, int cinemaId, String url, String name, String ll, Integer movieNumber, String phone,Boolean ischecked){
    this.context = context;
    this.cinemaId = cinemaId;
    this.name = name;
    this.url = url;
    this.ll = ll;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.movieNumber = movieNumber;
    this.checked = ischecked;
}
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

    FavouriteCinemasHelper dbHelper = new FavouriteCinemasHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    //boolean checked = menuItem.isChecked();
    String tableName = FavouriteCinemasContract.FavouriteCinemasRow.TABLE_NAME;

    if(checked == false){
        // Add to the DB
        //Step 1: Build a map of values to be inserted
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FavouriteCinemasContract.FavouriteCinemasRow.COLUMN_NAME_CINEMA_ID, cinemaId);
        values.put(FavouriteCinemasContract.FavouriteCinemasRow.COLUMN_NAME_CINEMA_NAME, name);
        values.put(FavouriteCinemasContract.FavouriteCinemasRow.COLUMN_NAME_CINEMA_URL, url);
        values.put(FavouriteCinemasContract.FavouriteCinemasRow.COLUMN_NAME_CINEMA_LL, ll);
        values.put(FavouriteCinemasContract.FavouriteCinemasRow.COLUMN_NAME_CINEMA_MOVIE_NUMBER, movieNumber);
        values.put(FavouriteCinemasContract.FavouriteCinemasRow.COLUMN_NAME_CINEMA_PHONE, phone);

        //Step 2: Run the query
        long newRowId;
        newRowId = db.insert(tableName, null, values);
        Log.wtf("InsertID", newRowId + "");
        menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_important);
        String removeReminder = new String("Remove from favourites");
        menuItem.setTitle(removeReminder);
    } else {
        // Delete
        String selection = FavouriteCinemasContract.FavouriteCinemasRow.COLUMN_NAME_CINEMA_ID + " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(cinemaId)};
        db.delete(tableName, selection, selectionArgs);
        menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_not_important);
        String removeReminder = new String("Add to favourites");
        menuItem.setTitle(removeReminder);
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358413/doesnt-call-onmenuitemclick-for-first-time-sherlocklistactivity